# Set JMeter properties using Maven plugin

Tags: maven, properties, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am using the Maven plugin for JMeter (http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/).

In my JMeter test plan I have defined various properties e.g. hostName, threadCount etc.

If I were to use the standard JMeter program from the command line I would specify the properties like this:

```
jmeter -n -t mytest.jmx -JhostName=www.example.com -JthreadCount=5
```

As the Maven JMeter plugin is executed via the following command:

```
mvn verify
```

How do I pass the property values? The command:

```
mvn verify -JhostName=www.example.com -JthreadCount=5
```

Does not seem to work. I must be missing something obvious

Answer (score 7):

Outside of your `<build>` block.  You can put:

```
  <properties>
    <my.host>localhost</my.host>
  </properties>
```

and then update your configuration block to say:

```
<propertiesUser> 
    <hostName>${my.host}</hostName> 
</propertiesUser>
```

Finally, when executing maven, you can override with:

```
mvn verify "-Dmy.host=www.testsite.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <properties>
<my.host>hostname</my.host>
```

```
<propertiesUser> 
<hostName>${my.host}</hostName>
```

Finally, when executing maven, you can override with:

mvn verify "-Dmy.host=www.testsite.com"
should it not be like this?