# Setting JMeter properties from Maven plugin

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm trying to set properties for a JMeter test using the Maven plugin. I've followed the recommended settings in my `pom.xml` file from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859085/set-jmeter-properties-using-maven-plugin), but my properties aren't getting picked up when the tests are run.

The relevant parts of the `pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jmeter-test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <propertiesUser>
                                    <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                                    <environment>test</environment>
                                </propertiesUser>
                                <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                                <proxyConfig>
                                    <host>localhost</host>
                                    <port>8888</port>
                                </proxyConfig>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I am trying to access the variables in my JMeter tests using: `${__P(threadCount)}` and `${__P(environment)}`.

When running, I'm using

```
mvn clean verify -Pjmeter-tests
```

I can see that the proxy configuration is being picked up and used from the output:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  P E R F O R M A N C E    T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Invalid value detected for <postTestPauseInSeconds>.  Setting pause to 0...
[INFO]
[INFO] Proxy Details:

Host: localhost:8888


[INFO]
[INFO] Executing test: JMeterTests.jmx
```

Unfortunately the `propertiesUser` values aren't getting used. I am also able to use the command line runner, which works as expected:

```
jmeter -n -t JMeterTests.jmx -Jenvironment=test -JthreadCount=5
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

**More info:**
I've been testing out using the [example project](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin-example), and see that the expected behaviour is that the configuration under `<propertiesUser>` is supposed to populate the file `target/jmeter/bin/user.properties`. This isn't happening, the file is not being created at all.

Answer (score 0):

See this FAQ:

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/FAQ

Moving the configuration outside the execution block should fix your problem:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jmeter-test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertiesUser>
                            <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                            <environment>test</environment>
                        </propertiesUser>
                        <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                        <proxyConfig>
                            <host>localhost</host>
                            <port>8888</port>
                        </proxyConfig>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```